# No results when comparing values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I just wrote the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * from (SELECT voornaam, achternaam, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geboortedatum, CURDATE())
AS Leeftijd FROM leiding)  
AS kolommen  
HAVING Leeftijd < AVG(Leeftijd)  
ORDER BY Leeftijd;
```

It doesn't return any results, but when I execute these queries seperately, they do give results:

```
SELECT AVG(Leeftijd) from (SELECT voornaam, achternaam, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geboortedatum, CURDATE()) AS Leeftijd FROM leiding) AS kolommen;
```

returns '19.3571', and

```
SELECT Leeftijd from (SELECT voornaam, achternaam, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geboortedatum, CURDATE()) AS Leeftijd FROM leiding) AS kolommen;
```

returns a list of ages, ranging from 25 to 18.
Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your outer select is completely redundant. And the title of this question does not relate well to your problem.

Comment: Not if I want to execute AVG(Leeftijd), right?

Comment: Okay, I changed it, but it's still not working: `SELECT voornaam, achternaam, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geboortedatum, CURDATE()) AS Leeftijd
 FROM leiding
 HAVING Leeftijd < AVG(Leeftijd)
    ORDER BY Leeftijd;`

Comment: in your query `having`is use with `group by` keyword

Comment: Okay, that should be WHERE, but the problem's still there: `SELECT voornaam, achternaam, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geboortedatum, CURDATE()) AS Leeftijd
 FROM leiding[
 WHERE Leeftijd < AVG(Leeftijd)
    ORDER BY Leeftijd;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combinaion of previous answers should work:

```
SELECT 
    voornaam, 
    achternaam, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geboortedatum, CURDATE()) AS Leeftijd
from 
    leiding
WHERE 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geboortedatum, CURDATE()) < (select AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geboortedatum, CURDATE())) from  leiding)
ORDER BY 
    Leeftijd
;
```

The first one is using aggregate function in WHERE clause, which is forbidden in SQL, the second one is using HAVING as WHERE which is just bad. Oh, and you fetched TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geboortedatum, CURDATE()) as Leeftijd, and probably You have column with that name in Your table...

So, this combination should work well for You.

Comment: Just wondering, isn't it a bad idea performance-wise to execute the same query 3 times?

Comment: Heh, the query plan creation and optimalization are quite more complex than You or I wloud like to know, so I can say: "it depends". :)
I will not change this to be less redundand, because MySQL do not support WITH clause, and without it, there will be no real gain here.

Remember [this](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score -1):

use `WHERE` instead `HAVING`. `HAVING` is use with `GROUP BY` keyword not single 
so write this query

```
SELECT * from (SELECT voornaam, achternaam, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geboortedatum, CURDATE())
AS Leeftijd FROM leiding)  
AS kolommen  
GROUP BY Leeftijd
HAVING Leeftijd < AVG(Leeftijd)  
ORDER BY Leeftijd;
```

> The MySQL HAVING clause is used in the SELECT statement to specify
>   filter conditions for a group of rows or aggregates.
>
> The MySQL HAVING clause is often used with the GROUP BY clause. When
>   using with the GROUP BY clause, we can apply a filter condition to the
>   columns that appear in the GROUP BY clause. If the GROUP BY clause is
>   omitted, the HAVING clause behaves like the WHERE clause.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx

Comment: This gives me an `Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function`

Comment: ok i understand why this error come. in this query use AVG function which is used with group by for aggregation.

Answer (score -1):

when you use select avg (column) in your query you get the average of your row value only not all your rows avg, so your query should be:

```
SELECT * from (SELECT voornaam, achternaam, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, geboortedatum, CURDATE())
AS Leeftijd FROM leiding)  
AS kolommen  
HAVING Leeftijd < (select AVG(Leeftijd) from  leiding)
ORDER BY Leeftijd;
```

Comment: This gives me an `Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns moer than 1 row`. Changing HAVING to WHERE solves the error, but still doesn't return any results.